# Can't login ORA-28031: maximum of 148 enabled roles exceeded

Tags: oracle

I can't login - and receive the error code above. How do I fix this?

Comment: Offtopic. not a programming question. This is db/server administration. Try the DBA site.

Comment: Cheers - sorry about that. ps. I was solving a programming problem - my automated tests wouldn't work because I had this error. I came to stackoverflow first. Hopefully others will find the migrated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, login as

```
SYSTEM@databasename AS SYSDBA
```

Then

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_ROLES;
```

Then for each role you don't want...

```
DROP ROLE <rolename>;
```

To drop roles.

If you have some pattern to the offending roles, you can use the following anonymous loop to clean those up. Imagine you had 50 roles with the word GILES in them which were generated from some erroneous SQL routine:

```
BEGIN
  FOR c IN ( SELECT ROLE FROM DBA_ROLES WHERE ROLE LIKE '%GILES%' )
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP ROLE ' || c.ROLE;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Don't ask me how to re-architect your roles, I'm no expert. I just had the same issue where some automated tests were creating roles but not dropping them.

I believe you can't alter the limit so discussions about the limit are pointless.

As Justin_Cave mentions, you can also revoke roles from users to deactivate them or make the role 'non default' which effectively reduces the active role count, and allows you to retain the role for future use.

Comment: This works if you happen to have a script that creates roles, that doesn't clean up after itself, and where you don't need the roles any longer.  In the general case, though, you'd want to revoke the role from the user (or make the role non-default).  That lets you keep the role (which is generally still useful).

Comment: Useful addition. Yes - you're right - if the roles are still useful, it's more about which roles are active.

Comment: -1, That is really a bad advice to drop roles to resolve this error. revoke the roles form the user that has the problem. If you have roles that where created erroneoulsy thatn drop them, even if you don't get a maximum-enabled-roles error. Besides that, initially SYSTEM does not has SYSDAB privileges and I don't think it is reasonable to grant this to it. If SYSTEM does not have SYSDBA privileges then your login will not work.

Comment: Miracle173 - I had just installed oracle server 11gr2 for this test and my SYSTEM user had SYSDBA privs by default. I don't think this is bad advice at all - if you have roles you do not use or need, the DBA should be dropping them, that's what I've said to do, and that fixed this particular problem in this scenario. I'm not saying there aren't other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

to let the user connect you need revoke some roles from the user

see discussion about here: AskTom

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1565923300346644029

the discussion about parameter `MAX_ENABLED_ROLES` that used to limit max count of roles to 150 roles. the parameter is marked as `deprecated` but as the discussion says it still had some value for limit

> It is deprecated because they are currently maxing it out (just like
>   maxtrans is deprecated - but still "exists", it is 255 no matter what
>   you set it to)
>   [MAX_ENABLED_ROLES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams130.htm)

```
Range of values 0 to 148
```

> deprecated
>
> MAX_ENABLED_ROLES specifies the maximum number of database roles that
>   users can enable, including roles contained within other roles. The
>   actual number of roles that users can enable is 2 plus the value of
>   MAX_ENABLED_ROLES, because each user has two additional roles, PUBLIC
>   and the user's own role.